# Use LDAP DirectorySearcher to determine if a user is a member of an AD group

Tags: vb.net, web-services, ldap, directoryservices, directorysearcher

I'm using LDAP to authenticate users of a internal corporate app.  The users must be a member of a particular AD group (NAV_Super) in order to gain access to the application.  The authentication method is working in that it confirms users have an active AD account but it is not restricting access to only members of the AD group (NAV_Super).  Basically any active AD account returns True.  Below is my code.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function ADCredentialCheck(ByVal InputUserName As String, InputPassword As String) As Boolean
    Dim MyDirectoryEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=NAV_Super,OU=Security Enabled Groups,OU=Groups,OU=MyCompany,DC=MyDomain,DC=com", InputUserName, InputPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
    Try
        Dim MyDirectorySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(MyDirectoryEntry)
        MyDirectorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user))"
        MyDirectorySearcher.FindOne()
        Return True
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```